# I dont get how to get the last equality in this calculation

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, integration, correlation-functions

In the calculation of equal-time spatial correlation of the electric field i have an idea of how to get the second equality (even if i miss that factor i/r) but I'm struggling to understand how the last equality is calculated.
(The integral $\int d\Omega exp(ikr)$ should give $4\pi sin(kr)/(kr)$)

[image: Calculation of equal-time spatial correlation of the electric field]

Comment: On Physics SE (and many other SE sites) [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is the preferred method of displaying equations.  We very strongly discourage using images of math or text.

Answer (score 0):

Do the $r$ derivatives and then use symmetric integration:
$$
\int k_i k_j d^d k =  \frac 1 d \delta_{ij}\int k^2 d^d k
$$